# Game won't work after I have change certificates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a small game that I want to put onto the app store but whenever I run the game it doesn't get past the initial app load screen. It used to work but I updated the code signing identity and bundle identifier and now it comes up with this :

[image]

this is in the CCNode.m file.

Just wondering if any new how the signing identities would have an effect like this.

Any help or thoughts is greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Ok so I have found that this was the issue, introLayer.mm file :

```
 -(id) init{
 if( (self=[super init])) {

    // ask director for the window size
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCSprite *background;

    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
        background.rotation = 90;
    } else {
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default-Landscape~ipad.png"];
    }
    background.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild: background];
}
return self;
```

}

the "Default.png" had to be changed to "Default@2x.png" for some reason, I have never changed this value before and it use to work, I find this to be a weird solution and one that it not correct(even though it makes the app work).

Could this be due to something in the appDelegate file(I have only changed this file to prevent the app from showing the FPS data)?

Any information on why the image would need the "@2x" added to it would be awesome.

Comment: Updating code sigining identity and bundle identifier will not effect your source code. It is clearly showing that your param child is nil so it should be some of your code changes.

Comment: you might have upgraded to new XCode.. this could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code error and won't be related to the certificate change. The `CCNode` being passed into that function is `nil` and that is triggering the `NSASSert`.

You need to investigate the cause for this: Try investigating the call stack to see where this function was called from - you are probably passing in an uninitialised object, or an object has been released where it shouldn't have been

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as it guided me towards the issue. Many thanks @davbryn. The actual problem seems to be that the "Default.png" image needed to e renamed to "Default@2x.png" I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Glad you sorted it! The @2x (I believe) is loaded on retina devices and should be a HD asset, so I guess you were running your code in the simulator and then deployed to a retina device?

Comment: I thought it was for that but I have been running on both the device and the simulator

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @davbryn in his answer, this not a signing issue. The only possibility that can make this bug is, you have done some conditional programming somewhere. I mean the code which initialises the CCNode object is surrounded by `#DEBUG` kind of statement and hence it is passes as `NULL`.